# Using classes and string vectors together in C++?

Tags: c++, string, class, vector

I'm just a beginner in C++ and I'm trying to get some vectors working for my program because I'm trying to write a program that allows the user to add/edit/remove previous entries from a file. Problem is I can't get my setters to work right with the vector. I'm not sure what exactly I'm doing wrong.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class DVD
{
public:
    //Default constructor
    DVD();
    //Class members
    vector<string> name[5];
    vector<string> length[5];
    vector<string> actora[5];
    vector<string> actorb[5];
    vector<string> year[5];
//Function to set and get DVD Name
void setDVDname(vector<string> name)
    {
        DVDname[5]=name[5];
    }
        vector<string> getDVDname()
    {
        return DVDname;
    }
//Function to set and get DVD length
void setDVDlength(vector<string> length)
    {
        DVDlength=length;
    }
        vector<string> getDVDlength()
    {
        return DVDlength;
    }
//Function to get and get DVD year
void setDVDyear(vector<string> year)
    {
        DVDyear=year;
    }
        vector<string> getDVDyear()
    {
        return DVDyear;
    }
//Function to get and set DVD Actor Alpha
void setDVDactorA(vector<string> actora)
    {
        DVDactorA=actora;
    }
        vector<string> getDVDactorA()
    {
        return DVDactorA;
    }

//Function to get and set DVD Actor Bravo
void setDVDactorB(vector<string> actorb)
    {
        DVDactorB=actorb;
    }
        vector<string> getDVDactorB()
    {
        return DVDactorB;
    }


protected:
private:
    //Variables to hold DVD information
    vector<string> DVDname[5];
    vector<string> DVDlength[5];
    vector<string> DVDactorA[5];
    vector<string> DVDactorB[5];
    vector<string> DVDyear[5];
 };
```

Comment: Do you really intend your member variables to be arrays of vectors of strings?

Comment: It's clear you're very confused about something, and possibly about many things. Would you consider buying a book on the subject and trying this project again when you're less confused?

Answer (score 2):

Since you're making a DVD library, you can do something like this:

```
class DVD {
    std::string name;
    // etc.
};
std::vector<DVD> library;
```

The `library` variable will be a list of DVDs that can hold as many DVDs as your computer's memory can handle. The purpose of using an `std::vector` is to not have to worry about managing the memory yourself. You just use `library.push_back()` to add more DVDs. If you want to see the other methods that `std::vector` provides, check out [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Logically, you want your DVD class to represent a DVD only, not a library or list of DVDs, so try to keep the two concepts separate in your code.

Comment: Thanks. That helps,I hadn't considered using a library function. I'm still sort of puzzled about the syntax though.

Comment: What part of the syntax are you struggling with?

Comment: Oh, I just found that strings are arrays of characters :\ that would have been useful to know before I changed my code. Now I can't get it to work. Oh well. There's just too much I don't understand right now to ask.I'll keep working at it and probably post questions as I run into more issues. Thanks for the help. :)

Answer (score 0):

Do you get any compile error is it logical?

Also, why do you use vector? Since it's one DVD and your vector correspond to information, simply remove the vector and make them simple strings.

Comment: The program calls for at least 5 entries because it's going to be a dvd library. I have gotten the string class to work in my compiler, although from what I was reading that vectors are the best way to have data that you can add/remove/edit members, and that's exactly what I need for my program.    The compiler error says that there is no match for 'operator ='

Answer (score 0):

First remove this, you don't use it and you don't need it. You set the value that this instance holds as private later. Also remove the protected keyword, you don't protect anything now.

```
//Class members
    vector<string> name[5];
    vector<string> length[5];
    vector<string> actora[5];
    vector<string> actorb[5];
    vector<string> year[5];
```

Second on the setDVDName() you pass one copy of a vector and then you assign only the last part which basically does not exist, since you vector has 5 elements and you request the 6th. You should change this to name[4] if you want the 5th element.

I assume that you want something like this instead: `DVDName = name;`
Also, change the declaration of the vectors.
From

```
//Variables to hold DVD information
vector<string> DVDname[5];
vector<string> DVDlength[5];
vector<string> DVDactorA[5];
vector<string> DVDactorB[5];
vector<string> DVDyear[5];
```

To:

```
//Variables to hold DVD information
vector<string> DVDname(5);
vector<string> DVDlength(5);
vector<string> DVDactorA(5);
vector<string> DVDactorB(5);
vector<string> DVDyear(5);
```

Comment: What if I changed it back to strings instead and do like dupersuper suggested and have a library class, would I be able to keep the setters are they are now?